Upgrade to spring boot 3.2.2 got exception : org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Redis command interrupted
After updating an application from Spring Boot 2.7 to Spring Boot 3.2.2, I encountered intermittent org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Redis command interrupted exceptions in a high-load environment. This issue occurred randomly, manifesting only twice over a span of 20 minutes within four days.
The same codebase, when run with Java 8 and Spring Boot 2.7, it works fine.
org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert (LettuceExceptionConverter.java:60)[-]
        org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert (LettuceExceptionConverter.java:41)
        org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate (PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:40)
        org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate (FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:38)
        org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.convertLettuceAccessException (LettuceConnection.java:306)
        org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.await (LettuceConnection.java:1010)
        org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.lambda$
<unresolved>.<unresolved> (<unresolved>)
        org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceInvoker$Synchronizer.invoke (LettuceInvoker.java:665)[-]
        org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceInvoker.just (LettuceInvoker.java:94)
        org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceStringCommands.get (LettuceStringCommands.java:54)
        org.springframework.data.redis.cache.DefaultRedisCacheWriter.lambda$
<unresolved>.<unresolved> (<unresolved>)
        org.springframework.data.redis.cache.DefaultRedisCacheWriter.execute (DefaultRedisCacheWriter.java:348)[-]
        org.springframework.data.redis.cache.DefaultRedisCacheWriter.get (DefaultRedisCacheWriter.java:140)
        org.springframework.data.redis.cache.DefaultRedisCacheWriter.get (DefaultRedisCacheWriter.java:129)
        org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.lookup (RedisCache.java:207)
        org.springframework.cache.support.AbstractValueAdaptingCache.get (AbstractValueAdaptingCache.java:58)


RedisCacheManager cacheManager;

public Object getObject(String key){
//Exception here
     Cache.ValueWrapper v=cacheManager.getCache(CACHE_NAME_PREFIX).get(key);

     return v!=null?v.get():null;
     }

@Cacheable(value = CACHE_NAME_PREFIX, key = CACHE_KEY)
public Object cacheObject(String cardNumber,String cacheKey){
     //Implementation.......
     }

     //Configuration:
@Bean(name = {"azureRedisTemplate"})
public StringRedisTemplate azureRedisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory){
     StringRedisTemplate template=new StringRedisTemplate();
     template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
     template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
     template.setValueSerializer(getGenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
     return template;
     }

@Primary
@Bean("redisCacheManager")
public RedisCacheManager cacheManager(){
     RedisCacheConfiguration configuration=
     RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
     .entryTtl(Duration.ofSeconds((long)this.cacheProperties.getTtl()))
     .serializeValuesWith(
     RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(
     getGenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer()))
     .serializeKeysWith(
     RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(
     new StringRedisSerializer()));
     return RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder.fromConnectionFactory(
     redisConnectionFactory())
     .cacheDefaults(configuration)
     .build();
     }

@Bean
RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory(){

       LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnFactory=null;

       if(vcapServices!=null){
       try{
       Map<String, Object> vcap=JsonUtil.parse(vcapServices);
     List<Object> azureRedisCache=(List<Object>)vcap.get(redisLable);
     Map<String, Object> credentials=
     JsonUtil.toMap(JsonUtil.toMap(azureRedisCache.get(0)).get("credentials"));
     RedisStandaloneConfiguration standaloneConfiguration=new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
     standaloneConfiguration.setPort(Integer.parseInt(credentials.get("sslPort").toString()));
     standaloneConfiguration.setHostName(credentials.get("hostname").toString());
     standaloneConfiguration.setPassword(
     RedisPassword.of(credentials.get("primaryKey").toString()));

     LettuceClientConfiguration lettuceClientConfiguration=
     LettuceClientConfiguration.builder().useSsl().disablePeerVerification().build();
     lettuceConnFactory=
     new LettuceConnectionFactory(standaloneConfiguration,lettuceClientConfiguration);
     }catch(Exception e){
     logger.error("Azure redis connection factory creation failed. ",e);
     }
     logger.debug("Azure redis connection factory initialized");
     }

     return lettuceConnFactory;
     }

I observed that the RedisConnectionFactory instances being used in RedisTemplate and RedisCacheManager are distinct from each other. Although this setup functions correctly in an environment with Java 8 and Spring Boot 2.7, I didn't change it.
Could you provide any insights into what might be causing this issue?
